# How to make an trigger in my server when dev make a commit

Tags: git, deployment, githooks

My company has in your server published an api, but when a dev make a commit I should be go to server and manually execute git pull command
How can I make an hook or task for execute `git pull` and `yarn start` before a dev send a commit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+%22push+to+deploy%22

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+%22push+to+deploy%22+%22post-update%22